# Preserve order of array elements after unnest and array_agg in AWS Athena / Presto

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have an Athena query that unnests an array, join the elements with another table, and then collects them back into an array using `array_agg`. I want to preserve the original order of the elements, but Athena does not support the Presto feature to add an `ORDER BY` clause to `array_agg`. How can I preserve the order of elements?

The query is similar to this example:

```sql
SELECT x, array_agg(b) bs
FROM table1 -- table1 columns are x, ys
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ys) AS t(y)
JOIN table2 ON y=a -- table2 columns are a, b
GROUP BY x
```

1. The default behavior seems to be to preserve the order. Is it reliable?
2. If not (1), is there an implementation that would preserve the order of `ys` in `bs`?

Answer (score 3):

had same problem, my workaround is to aggregate values to map with ordinality as key. and then to transform values of map to array(ordered by keys):

```
SELECT t1.x, 
       transform(sequence(1,cardinality(map_agg(n,y)),(x)-> map_agg(n,y)[x]) 
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN 
UNNEST(t1.ys) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(y, n) JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.y = t2.a
GROUP BY t1.x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Presto supports [`unnest()` `with ordinality`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```
SELECT t1.x, array_agg(t2.b ORDER BY n) bs
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN 
     UNNEST(t1.ys) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(y, n) JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.y = t2.a
GROUP BY t1.x;
```

Note that you don't need comments to specify where columns come from.  Just quality the column reference with the appropriate table alias.  This also makes the query unambiguous and easier to understand.

Comment: PrestoDB supports array_agg with OREDER BY, but sadly, Athena, that is not 100% presto, does not :(

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables . . . Well, it should work with PrestoDB at least.  There may not be a way to do what you want on Athena.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Athena is maybe a bit behind the newest Presto always. But for new readers I can confirm it is supported now and working.

Answer (score 1):

One way to preserve the order without `ORDER BY`:

1. prefix each output value with a sort string
2. aggregate into the unsorted array
3. sort the array
4. remove the sort prefix from each array element

```
SELECT
x
-- prefix each "b" with a 19-digit sortable string
-- aggregate into array, sort, then remove the prefix
, TRANSFORM(
  ARRAY_SORT(
    array_agg(
      SUBSTR(LPAD(CAST(yi AS VARCHAR), 19, '0'), -19)
      || b))
  , e1 -> SUBSTR(e1, 1 + 19)
  ) AS bs
FROM table1 -- table1 columns are x, ys
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ys) WITH ORDINALITY t (y, yi)
JOIN table2 ON y = a -- table2 columns are a, b
GROUP BY x
```

This method assumes:

- the sortable data will fit into a varchar array column
- `b` is character data (or readily convertible)